# Magento 2 - override Collapsible knockoutjs template located in base folder

Tags: magento2.4

```
app/code/Vendor/modulename/view/base/web/templates/dynamic-rows/templates/collapsible.html
```

```
<div class="admin__field-control" data-role="grid-wrapper">
    <div class="admin__control-table-pagination" visible="!!element.getRecordCount()">
        <div class="admin__data-grid-pager">
            <button class="action-previous" type="button" data-bind="attr: {title: $t('Previous Page')}, click: previousPage, disable: isFirst()"></button>
            <input class="admin__control-text" type="number" data-bind="attr: {id: ++ko.uid}, value: currentPage">
            <label class="admin__control-support-text" data-bind="attr: {for: ko.uid}, text: 'of ' + pages()"></label>
            <button class="action-next" type="button" data-bind="attr: {title: $t('Next Page')}, click: nextPage, disable: isLast()"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table class="admin__dynamic-rows admin__control-collapsible" data-role="grid" attr="'data-index': index">

        <thead if="element.columnsHeader">
        <tr data-bind="foreach: {data: labels, as: 'label'}">
            <th translate="label.config.label"
                css="item.columnsHeaderClasses">
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody data-bind="foreach: elems">
        <tr class="data-row" data-bind="foreach: {data: elems, as: 'elem'}">
            <td css="$parents[1].setClasses(elem)" if="elem.template">
                <div class="fieldset-wrapper admin__collapsible-block-wrapper"
                     collapsible="openClass: '_show', closeOnOuter: false, opened: elem.opened(false)">
                    <div class="fieldset-wrapper-title">

                        <div class="admin__collapsible-title" data-role="collapsible-title" click="elem.toggleOpened">
                            <render args="name: $parents[1].dndConfig.template, data: $parents[1].dnd"
                                    if="$parents[1].dndConfig.enabled" />

                            <span translate="$parent.getLabel(elem)" />
                        </div>

                        <button class="action-delete"
                                data-index="delete_button"
                                type="button"
                                title="'Delete'"
                                click="function(){
                                        $parents[1].deleteHandler($parent.index, $parent.recordId)
                                    }">
                            <span translate="'Delete'"/>
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="admin__collapsible-content"
                         css="{_show: $data.opened()}"
                         data-role="collapsible-content"
                         template="elem.template"></div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div class="admin__control-table-action" if="element.addButton">
        <button attr="{disabled: disabled}"
                type="button"
                click="addChild.bind($data, false, false)">
            <span translate="addButtonLabel"/>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

app/code/vendor/modulename/view/base/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/templates/dynamic-rows/templates/collapsible":
                "Vendor_Modulename/templates/dynamic-rows/templates/collapsible"
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: check magento vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/requirejs-config.js file.

It would help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check below ways.

your template file path should be.

> app/code/{{vendor}}/{{modulename}}/view/base/web/templates/dynamic-rows/templates/collapsible.html

and your requirejs-config.js file path should be.

> app/code/{{vendor}}/{{modulename}}/view/base/requirejs-config.js

**requirejs-config.js** file

```
var config = {
    map: {
        "*": {
            'ui/template/dynamic-rows/templates/collapsible.html':'{{vendorname_modulename}}/templates/dynamic-rows/templates/collapsible.html'
        }
    }
};
```

after update it execute setup upgrade and content-deploy command.

Comment: you can get help from "vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/requirejs-config.js".

Comment: it's working for me .thanks